# What is the easiest way to get a list of the keywords in a string?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, formatting

For example:

```
str = 'abc{text}ghi{num}'
```

I can then do

```
print(str.format(text='def',num=5))
> abcdefghi5
```

I would like to do something like

```
print(str.keywords) # function does not exist
> ['text','num']
```

What is the easiest way to do this? I can search character-by-character for `{` and `}` but I wonder if there a built-in python function?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [`string.Formatter` class](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/string.html#string.Formatter):

```
>>> import string
>>> text = 'abc{text}ghi{num}'
>>> [t[1] for t in string.Formatter().parse(text)]
['text', 'num']
```